# Is it possible the argument for frame is passed as an argument to another frame in backtrace even when data types are different

Tags: c++, vxworks

In my application which is deployed on vxWorks following **backtrace** (generated on xrtc file) is generated:

```
 d475c (Frame 1) process_host_invoke+274: d3bac (ffffff00, 3e8)
 d3cac (Frame 2) stop_feature_monitor+904: receive_invoke_reply ()
 d0318 (Frame 3) receive_invoke_reply+7c : wait_reply_msg (3e8, 7950818, ffffff00)
 cc6a4 (Frame 4) wait_reply_msg+98 : semTake (ffffff00, 3e8)
859690 (Frame 5) semTake        +28 : vxWorks_semTake (ffffff00, 3e8)
```

Following are the prototype of methods invoked above:

```
void process_host_invoke(X *param);
int wait_reply_msg(uchar **msg,int* size,int wait_tick );

STATUS semTake(
SEM_ID semId,  /* semaphore ID to take */
int    timeout /* timeout in ticks */
);
```

Is it possible that argument of type uchar **msg from frame 3 is passed on to frame 5 as an argument even when the data types are different.

I am new to **vxWorks** environment. Is it possible that function arguments are passed incorrectly on stack.

FFFFFF00 (H)--> 4,294,967,040‬ this value is passed as SEM_ID in semTake‬
I got **S_objLib_OBJ_ID_ERROR** when semTake is invoked.

PS: I don't have dump file

Comment: I am not familiar with vxWorks, but it definitely looks like you have some kind of mismatch there - perhaps an incorrect version of the headers relative to the libraries that you are using.

Comment: the issue happening when invalid ID is passed to semTake. However, semTake is a system call, so I don't think so it could be version mismatch. The same code has been working when we restart the application. This is our legacy code, it has been in use from past many years. We are trying to find the root cause of the issue. Let me know if some more details are required, will provide the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that function arguments are passed incorrectly on stack.

Yes, definitely possible. I've seen such behavior for task trace when working with old version of VxWorks running on MIPS32 processors. MIPS [calling convetions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS) doesn't require putting function arguments on stack, they are passed through registers and may not appear on stack at all. Not sure if it was the reason, but function call parameters were never accurate in traces for me.